# How can I get the second array?

Tags: php

I have an array which returns:

```
Array
    (
        [] => Array
            (
                [first_name] => Charles
                [last_name] => Darwin
                [title] => 1
                [academic_unit] => 2
            )

    )
```

I want to get the second array. How can I do that?

Comment: What exactly does `var_dump(key($array))` give you?

Comment: [`reset($array)['first_name'];`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can access it like this

```
 $array[null]['first_name']
 //or this which saves you a cast from null to an empty string
 $array['']['first_name']
```

"[] => Array" means that the index is an empty string

`null` will be casted internally to an empty string

```
$array = array(null => array('hello'));
print_r($array);
```

Results in

```
Array
(
    [] => Array
        (
            [0] => hello
        )
)
```

From the docs: "Additionally the following key casts will occur"
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Null will be cast to the empty string, i.e. the key null will actually be stored under "".